# Cannot copy and resample an image with PHP

Tags: php, image, gdlib

I am trying to copy a resampled image. Something seems not working:

```
copy($_FILES['image']['name'],'logo.png');
$dir_subida = 'C:\xampp5\htdocs\bild';
$source = imagecreatefrompng($_FILES['image']['name']);
$destination = imagecreatefrompng($dir_subida . '\\logo.png');
imagecopyresampled($destination,$source,0,0,0,0,110,55,600,220);
```

First I copy the image and save it in a directory. Then, I define the source (an image that I am uploading in a form). Then I define the destination.

Then I try to resample and copy it with the default function imagecopyresampled.

It just copies the image right away without any kind of changes.

Am I missing something?

Comment: When you ask a question about an error, **ALWAYS** post the error log. To enable error reporting to your php code, append `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', '1');` at the top of your script, what does it return ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must save the destination image to a file after you manipulate it.

```
imagepng($destination, 'c:\\path\\to\\file.png');
```